# How to increase the height of the column header of a table?

Tags: tables, longtable

There is a long table

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing

%%% Tables.
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
%
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Caption of Table
\usepackage[format=hang,
            labelsep = space,
            skip=1ex, 
            singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

%%% Page
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm, right=15mm}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\sisetup{table-column-width=7.5ex}
\begin{longtable}[l]{c  S[table-format= 4.1]
                        S[table-format=-3.1, table-column-width=9.5ex]
                        S[table-format=-3.1]
                        S[table-format= 1.4]
                        S[table-format= 1.2]
                        S[table-format=-2.1]
                        S[table-format=-2.1]
                        }
\caption{--- Caption of long table}
    \label{tableLabel} \\
    \toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{Date}
        &   {\multirow{3}{*}{\makecell{Ratio of the \\ volume of, \\ transactions \\ to the number \\ of transactions \\ EURO}}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Absolute \\ increases, \\ EURO}}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Coefficients}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Rates of\\ growth \%}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-8}
        &   &   {chain}
                &   {base}
                    &   {chain}
                        &   {base}
                            &   {chain}
                                &   {base}                                  \\
    \midrule
    {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8}                           \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    %
\multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation \ref{tableLabel}}                     \\
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Date}
        &   {\multirow{3}{*}{\makecell{Ratio of the \\ volume of, \\ transactions \\ to the number \\ of transactions \\ EURO}}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Absolute \\ increases}}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Coefficients}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Rates of\\ growth \%}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-8}
        &   &   {chain}
                &   {base}
                    &   {chain}
                        &   {base}
                            &   {chain}
                                &   {base}                                  \\
    \midrule
    {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8}                           \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation \ref{tableLabel} on the next page\ldots}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
    %
30.09.2014  & 1438  & {--} & {--} & {--} & 1 & {--} & {--} \\
01.10.2014  & 1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
    \addlinespace
07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
    \addlinespace
01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
    \addlinespace
08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
    \addlinespace
02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
    \addlinespace
09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
    \addlinespace
03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
06.10.2014&574,8&-110,7&-863,2&0,839&0,4&-16,1&-60 \\
07.10.2014&620,7&45,9&-817,3&1,08&0,43&8&-56,8 \\
08.10.2014&696,9&76,2&-741,1&1,123&0,48&12,3&-51,5 \\
09.10.2014&647,1&-49,8&-790,9&0,929&0,45&-7,1&-55 \\
    \addlinespace
10.10.2014&734,6&87,5&-703,4&1,135&0,51&13,5&-48,9 \\
13.10.2014&764,8&30,2&-673,2&1,041&0,53&4,1&-46,8 \\
01.10.2014&1358,6&-79,4&-79,4&0,945&0,94&-5,5&-5,5 \\
02.10.2014&796,3&-562,3&-641,7&0,586&0,55&-41,4&-44,6 \\
03.10.2014&685,5&-110,8&-752,5&0,861&0,48&-13,9&-52,3 \\
    \addlinespace
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

This table has a lot of text in the header of the second column. This text goes beyond his cell.

[image]

How to increase the header height of the second column, so that the text fit in the height?

Comment: Use more rows. You specify that you use 3 rows in the `\multirow{3}...` statement but inside that `\multirow` you use `\makecell` with 5 rows. `\multirow` doesn't use more vertical space than you tell it to. Or use a shorter table header.

Comment: I solved the problem. I will write later about it.

Comment: Good to hear. Maybe you could post your solution as an answer to your question. This way others may find the solution if they encounter the same or a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

[image]

it is not possible put an elephant in suitcase ...

there are two possible solutions:

- make second column header shorter and give its explanation in bottom of the table (as shown images above). for this solution you need to change the following table code lines:

```
\sisetup{table-column-width=6.5ex}
\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}c  
                        S[table-column-width=11ex,
                          table-format= 4.1]
                        S[table-format=-3.1]
                        S[table-format=-3.1]
                        S[table-format= 1.4]
                        S[table-format= 1.2]
                        S[table-format=-2.1]
                        S[table-format=-2.1]
                        @{}}
\caption{--- Caption of long table}
    \label{tableLabel} \\
    \toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{Date}
        &   {\multirow{3}{*}[1ex]{\makecell{Ratio V/N\\ transactions$^*$\\ EURO}}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Absolute increases, \\ EURO}}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Coefficients}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Rates of\\ growth \%}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        &   &   {chain}
                &   {base}
                    &   {chain}
                        &   {base}
                            &   {chain}
                                &   {base}                                  \\
    \midrule
    {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8}                           \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    %
\multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation \ref{tableLabel}}                     \\
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Date}
        &   {\multirow{3}{*}[1ex]{\makecell{Ratio V/N\\ transactions$^*$\\ EURO}}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Absolute \\ increases}}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Coefficients}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Rates of\\ growth \%}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        &   &   {chain}
                &   {base}
                    &   {chain}
                        &   {base}
                            &   {chain}
                                &   {base}                                  \\
    \midrule
    {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8}                           \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\footnotesize
$^*$: Ratio of the volume of, transactions to the number of transactions in EURO}
    &   \multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize Continuation on the next page}
\endfoot
   \bottomrule
 \multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{\footnotesize
$^*$: Ratio of the volume of, transactions to the number of transactions in EURO}
\endlastfoot
```

- or use smaller font for second column head:

[image]

where you need to change the following table code lines as follows:

```
\sisetup{table-column-width=6ex}
\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}c  
                        S[table-column-width=13ex,
                          table-format= 4.1]
                        S[table-format=-3.1]
                        S[table-format=-3.1]
                        S[table-format= 1.4]
                        S[table-format= 1.2]
                        S[table-format=-2.1]
                        S[table-format=-2.1]
                     @{}}   
\caption{--- Caption of long table}
    \label{tableLabel} \\
    \toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{Date}
        &   {\multirow{3}{*}[1ex]{\footnotesize\makecell{Ratio of the volume\\ 
                                    of,  transactions to the \\ 
                                    number of transactions\\ 
                                    EURO}}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Absolute increases, \\ EURO}}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Coefficients}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Rates of\\ growth \%}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        &   &   {chain}
                &   {base}
                    &   {chain}
                        &   {base}
                            &   {chain}
                                &   {base}                                  \\
    \midrule
    {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8}                           \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    %
\multicolumn{8}{r}{Table continuation \ref{tableLabel}}                     \\
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Date}
        &   {\multirow{3}{*}[1ex]{\footnotesize\makecell{Ratio of the volume\\
                                    of,  transactions to the \\
                                    number of transactions\\
                                    EURO}}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Absolute \\ increases}}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Coefficients}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Rates of\\ growth \%}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        &   &   {chain}
                &   {base}
                    &   {chain}
                        &   {base}
                            &   {chain}
                                &   {base}                                  \\
    \midrule
    {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8}                           \\
    \midrule
\endhead
```

in both cases is also needed to redefine column width. i would select the first case. beside described there are probably other solution too, but this i left to other answers (if will be any)

Comment: I would like to ask you. How does the table-format work? I understand that it moves the columns of the table. And I read the documentation on the Internet about him. But still did not fully understand. At me such questions: 1) What is the difference between + and - before the number of table-format? 2) What is the difference between the numeral before the separating point and after?

Comment: `table-format` determine formatting numbers in column. sign`-` make space reservation for sign - (if number is negative) , first number  make reservation for integer digits of number, the second number make space reservation for decimal digits. details for formatting tabular materials with `siunitx` you can find in package documentation (section *5.14 Tabular material* on page 44), which is part of `siunitx` installation. an example: `S[table-format=-3.1]` make space reservation for numbers with 3 integer digits, 1 decimal digit and space for - sign, if number is negative.